# Is Ionic+Vue as frontend combinable with Umbraco as backend? (Webpack frustrations)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, ionic4, umbraco

My first question here on Stackoverflow :) I'm trying to make an app with Ionic&Vue, and as a CMS I'm using Umbraco. I want to connect the two, which I'm now trying by configuring Webpack, so that Webpack will take my main.ts file that Ionic&Vue created and do stuff with it and put it in the main Umbraco folder as a source file where I can reference Umbraco content.

I'm not having a lot of luck with it unfortunately. I've tried configuring a webpack.config.js file and installing a bunch of libraries like 'vue-loader', 'ts-loader', 'vue-template-compiler', 'vue-style-loader' et cetera. Some stuff is getting compiled, it's just that I keep getting an error that there's a mismatch in versions (vue is @3.0.2 and vue-template-compiler is @2.6.12). Ionic won't work with Vue under version 3 though so I feel like I'm stuck.

So my question: am I missing something? Is it really not possible or is there another way to compile a file from .ts to .js to a folder of my wish?

Edit (webpack config file):

```
var { HotModuleReplacementPlugin } = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
var ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    let transpileOnly = argv.transpileOnly === 'true';

    return {
        entry: './src/main.ts',

        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: 'bundledwebpack.js'
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "ts-loader",
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    // Now we apply rule for images
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            // Using file-loader for these files
                            loader: "file-loader",

                            // In options we can set different things like format
                            // and directory to save
                            options: {
                                outputPath: 'images'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    // Apply rule for fonts files
                    test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            // Using file-loader too
                            loader: "file-loader",
                            options: {
                                outputPath: 'fonts'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader',
                    options: {
                        loaders: {
                            'scss': [
                                'vue-style-loader',
                                'css-loader',
                                'sass-loader'
                            ],
                            'sass': [
                                'vue-style-loader',
                                'css-loader',
                                'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                            ]
                        },
                        compiler: '@vue/compiler-sfc'

                    }
                }
            ]
        },

        plugins: [
            new HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),


        ].concat(transpileOnly ? [
            new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
                reportFiles: ['src/**/*.{ts,tsx,vue}', '!src/**/*.js.vue'],
                tslint: true,
                vue: true
            })
        ] : [])
        ,

        mode: 'development'
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with Vue dependencies here, looks like you need to config Webpack properly. Can you share your webpack config file?

Comment: Hi @DavidGo, I've added the Webpack config file :)

Answer (score -1):

This sounds more like a vue issue than a Umbraco one.  You should be able to do it.  After a quick google there is a working project here:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-vue-conference-app

Have you tried explicitly installing packages with version numbers that work, e.g.

```
npm install @ionic/vue@0.0.4
```